# How to compare FullDefinition of two function to check if they are actually equal?

Tags: functions

I usually use [WReach's define tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769335/1911722) to define new functions.

For example, running

```
define[f[x_]:=x]
FullDefinition[f]
```

we got a bunch of definitions.

```
f[x_]:=x
 
def$:f[___]:=(Message[define::badargs,f,def$];Abort[])


 
Attributes[def$]={Temporary}
 
Attributes[define]={HoldAll}
 
define[body_,attribute_Symbol]:=define[body,{attribute}]
 
define[body:_Set|_SetDelayed,attributes_List:{}]:=define[CompoundExpression[body],attributes]
 
define[body:CompoundExpression[(Set|SetDelayed)[name_Symbol[___],_]..],attributes_List:{}]:=(ClearAll[name];SetAttributes[name,DeleteCases[attributes,Open]];If[!MemberQ[attributes,Open],def:name[___]:=(Message[define::badargs,name,def];Abort[])];body;)
 
def:define[___]:=(Message[define::malformed,def];Abort[])


 
define/:define::badargs=There is no definition for '``' applicable to ``.
 
define/:define::malformed=Malformed definition: ``
```

Now I define another function

```
define[g[x_]:=x]
```

We know function `g` is actually equivalent to `f` except with a different name. Is there a way to have a function

```
compareFullDefinition[f,g]
```

that check this actual equivalence and will give True for this case?

Comment: Can you explain the context in which you need this? I’m failing to imagine a use case so I have a hard time thinking of a useful approach.

Comment: @MarcoB   I have an evaluation process depends on a function which is slow, but it can be ran over and over to  get finer result based on previous result. In each cycle, I dump the result as well as the function which I used to do the evaluation. In the next run, I want to first compare the dumped function definition to the one I passed, so that I won't  mess thing up if I mistakenly pass a different function from the previous one.

Comment: Might you be able to use hashing in any way?

Comment: @J.M. any explanation? :)

Comment: I was speculating whether someone might think of hashing the e.g. `DownValues[]` somehow, after making some obvious function name replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get `Information` for both functions and change the information into a list. Now we replace the the name of the first function by the name of the second function. Unfortunately the names appear not only as symbols, but also in strings. Therefore we need to throw out these strings. After having prepared the lists, we can finally compare them:

```
CompareFullDefinition[f_, g_] := Module[{t1, t2},
  t1 = Normal[Information[f][[1]]] /. {f -> g, 
     HoldPattern[Rule["Usage", _]] -> Nothing, 
     HoldPattern["FullName" -> _] -> Nothing};
  t2 = Normal[Information[g][[1]]] /. {f -> g, 
     HoldPattern[Rule["Usage", _]] -> Nothing, 
     HoldPattern["FullName" -> _] -> Nothing};
  t1 === t2
  ]

CompareFullDefinition[f, g]
(*True*)
```

Comment: Hi, Daniel Huber. It seems does not work. No matter what the definition of g is, it all gives True.

Comment: `FullDefinition[f] // FullForm` just gives `FullDefinition[f]`. It doesn't actually evaluate to anything; all it does it give the FE the task to print the definitions.

Comment: That was bit trickier than I thought.   As said by Sjoerd, `FullDefinition` does actually not evaluate until printing. That is why we always get `True`.  We need to use  `Information` plus some fiddling to get the right answer. I corrected my answer. Hope I did not get tricked again.

Comment: Great job! It seems working at far as I can see. `Information` did not come to my mind back then :)